# What is the logic behind Assignments in Conditionals and Assignments in Returns

Tags: javascript

I will not bore you with the story, but essentially I have some obscured JavaScript to deal with which all in all is fine, but I am struggling with 2 patterns in the code which I have never seen before.

This function below contains both patterns.

```
var a = function() {
            if (h = true,
            T(),
            DEVELOPMENT && "#y0" == window.location.hash)
                return game.playRegion = "eu",
                game.playRoom = "ffa1",
                game.playInvited = true,
                game.myOriginalName = window.location.hash.substr(1),
                void Games.start(game.myOriginalName, true);
            f || (I(),
            Games.updateRegion(false),
            Games.updateType(false),
            C())
        }
```

1. First look at the `if` statement. I have never seen a `if` do assignment and call functions so I do not understand the logic of the conditional. Can I move the statements above the `if` or do the statements not run unless the full condition is met?  Can I do this:

```
h = true;
T();
if (DEVELOPMENT && window.location.hash === "#y0"){}
```

2. What is going on with the `return`? The return is a series of statements so what is it actually returning?  What is the `void` all about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nearly everything is an expression in JavaScript.

Assignments are also just expressions. `a = b` evaluates to `b`.

The Comma operator (which is used quite extensively) evaluates to the right side of the comma, so `a, b, c` evaluates to `c`.

`void` takes any expression, and always evaluates to `undefined`.

Therefore this:

```
 return a = b, void c();

 if(d(), e) {}
```

equals:

```
 a = b;
 c();
 return undefined;

 d();
 if(e) {}
```

Comment: Thank you Jonas! I have been using Actionscript and these days TypeScript for a long time and my JavaScript fundamentals are clearly more lacking that I imagined. Appreciate your time.

Comment: ... well no one would ever use the comma operator / `void` ... so you  will most likely never need this knowledge ;)